# Is there a Spanish equivalent to the English phrase "leave it all on the field"?

Tags: traducción, hispanoamérica, solicitud-de-modismo, deportes

In English, athletes who participate in competitions (especially important ones) discuss their effort as "leaving it all on the field". This gives the sense that there was (or will be) nothing held back or reserved for later.

Clearly, this could be translated as "poner el máximo esfuerzo", "darlo todo", or something similar, but I would like to know if there is some Spanish phrase that retains the idea of the event itself. For example, would (and I'm just making this up) "dejar el alma en la cancha/el campo" or "no quedar nada para después del juego" convey the idea?

Comment: Good question! Do you aim for an expression from any specific Spanish speaking region?

Comment: Perhaps North American or Caribbean. My audience will likely not include individuals from Spain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As much as *darlo todo*, I also hear often ***dejar(se) la piel (en el campo)***:

> [**dejar alguien la piel**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Sx8TogY)
>   1. loc. verb. coloq. dar la piel.
>   2. loc. verb. coloq. Esforzarse al máximo en algo. U. m. con el verbo c. prnl. *Se deja la piel en su trabajo*.

Literally, it translates as *to leave the skin (somewhere)*, and it [probably comes from](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/dejarse-la-piel.2414957/) the image of slaves working while being lashed.

So it is quite common to read things like:

> El Barça cayó derrotado pese a dejarse la piel en el campo hasta el último momento.

<sub>(todos sabemos que eso es falso, porque el Barça gana siempre)</sub>

I say this from my Spanish from Spain perspective and I am not quite sure of how common this meaning is in Central and North America. Some Googling showed some results in that region, but I would appreciate some confirmation from people from there.

Comment: ¿Sabías que [_culé_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BcoYDXE) aparece en el DLE? Y ya puestos, las acepciones madridistas de [_merengue_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=P0BmXOB) también. Lo que no sabía era que venía (tal vez) del catalán _culer_ 'trasero, culera'. ¿Crees que su posible etimología daría para una pregunta? :-D

Comment: @CarlosAlejo ¡anda! No sabía que estuviera en el DLE (¡y veo que [colchonero](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9kCA7je) también!). Pues [su origen](https://ca.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culer) es bastante conocido por esta zona: en el campo viejo del Barça la gente se sentaba sobre un muro para ver los partidos. Como esa pared rodeaba el campo, los viandantes veían una fila de culos cuando pasaban por allí :) En el artículo hay una foto muy descriptiva jeje.

Answer (score 5):

The sentence *darlo todo* is a good option, as it carries the meaning of "leave it all". If you want, you can add *en el campo*, *en la cancha*, *en el terreno de juego*, or whatever expression the same way as you say "on the field".

I found [one example](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=1&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=110417%5C010%5CC000O11042017100905462.1220.1216&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20darlo%20todo%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCREA%20%7B%7CI%7D%20,%20en%20%7BI%7DCOSTA%20RICA,%20CUBA,%20EE.%20UU.,%20M%C9XICO,%20PUERTO%20RICO,%20REP.%20DOMINICANA%20%7B%7CI%7D%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto1) in the CREA reference corpus of the expression used in a newspaper from Mexico (emphasis mine):

> "Todo puede pasar. Hoy tuve una carrera perfecta y estoy agradecida con Dios por la oportunidad de correr una final olímpica. Ahora hay que salir **a darlo todo**, a morirme en la raya para completar una misión", dice luego de tomar una pausa.
>
> PRENSA, "Excélsior, 25/09/2000 : Ana hizo realidad su sueño, estará en la final", 2000 (México).

In this case the expression is used by itself. In the next expression she adds *en la raya*, meaning the finish line, implying that she will die while crossing that line if needed to win the competition.

Answer (score 4):

En México usamos el pintoresco

> ***[echar toda la carne al asador](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7bnjWlr%7C7bpKzqY#7giALBz)***
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Arriesgarlo todo de una vez, o llevar al extremo el empeño y esfuerzo en la ejecución de algo.

Es decir, invertir todos los recursos, sin reservas, a un proceso irreversible; esperando el resultado más favorable.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the most exact translation could be "Dejarse la piel" or even "Dejarse el pellejo"

In Reverso dictionary:

> [**dejarse la piel**](http://diccionario.reverso.net/espanol-definiciones/dejarse%20la%20piel): hacer un esfuerzo agotador en la realización de una tarea.
>
> [**dejarse el pellejo**](http://diccionario.reverso.net/espanol-definiciones/dejarse%20el%20pellejo): acabar exhausto luego de esforzarse mucho en un trabajo o tarea.